# Is a firewall blocking me from accessing VZW's website?

Tags: networking, firewall, traceroute, nmap

I am not able to get on Verizon Wireless's website http://www.verizonwireless.com/ from any computer on my LAN. Chrome and Firefox just return with a connection timed out. However, the name resolves fine and other websites work. I CAN reach it from my phone (4G) or from another location through a VPN. To troubleshoot, I did a traceroute from the VPN, which returned:

```
$ sudo nmap -sS -Pn --traceroute www.verizonwireless.com

Starting Nmap 5.51 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-10-10 21:00 CDT
Nmap scan report for www.verizonwireless.com (162.115.18.200)
Host is up (0.049s latency).
rDNS record for 162.115.18.200: cascrmdinet51-ns-www.verizonwireless.com
Not shown: 998 filtered ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
80/tcp  open  http
443/tcp open  https

TRACEROUTE (using port 443/tcp)
HOP RTT      ADDRESS
1   0.17 ms  --
2   0.62 ms  --
3   0.81 ms  --
4   1.40 ms  --
5   1.83 ms  --
6   2.63 ms  xe-10-3-0-126.bar2.Houston1.Level3.net (4.59.129.81)
7   ... 8
9   6.98 ms  verizon-level3-2x10g.dallas3.level3.net (4.68.62.166)
10  ...
11  46.29 ms gigabitethernet6-0-0.gw10.sac1.alter.net (152.63.48.97)
12  47.22 ms vzw-gw.customer.alter.net (157.130.202.46)
13  ... 15
16  48.75 ms cascrmdinet51-ns-www.verizonwireless.com (162.115.18.200)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 16.67 seconds
```

But if I run it from my computer:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap>nmap -sS -Pn --traceroute www.verizonwireless.com

Starting Nmap 6.49BETA5 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2015-10-10 21:00 Central Daylight Time
Nmap scan report for www.verizonwireless.com (162.115.18.200)
Host is up.
rDNS record for 162.115.18.200: cascrmdinet51-ns-www.verizonwireless.com
All 1000 scanned ports on www.verizonwireless.com (162.115.18.200) are filtered

TRACEROUTE (using proto 1/icmp)
HOP RTT      ADDRESS
1   0.00 ms  --
2   15.00 ms --
3   16.00 ms --
4   18.00 ms --
5   24.00 ms hu-3-7-0-0-cr01.dallas.tx.ibone.comcast.net (68.86.91.249)
6   23.00 ms be-17-pe02.1950stemmons.tx.ibone.comcast.net (68.86.83.122)
7   24.00 ms 66.208.229.170
8   ...
9   60.00 ms GigabitEthernet6-0-0.GW10.SAC1.ALTER.NET (152.63.48.97)
10  ... 27
28  56.00 ms vzw-gw.customer.alter.net (157.130.202.46)
29  ... 30

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 212.61 seconds
```

... it never reaches the website (cascrmdinet51-ns-www.verizonwireless.com (162.115.18.200)). Is something behind vzw-gw.customer.alter.net (157.130.202.46) blocking my connections?

--- EDIT 1---

I have tried bypassing my router entirely by connecting my computer directly to the modem. My computer currently has my public IP address, which hasn't changed,  (after spoofing my modem's MAC address) and is still unable to reach www.verizonwireless.com. I cannot change my IP address even after a

```
ipconfig /release
net stop dhcp
net start dhcp
ipconfig /renew
```

and deleting the DHCP lease from the registry. I'm guessing this is normal operation since the lease is still valid on Comcast's side? The only other way would be for me to call Comcast and associate a different MAC address, but I'd definitely like to avoid that if possible. Both Comcast's and VZW's support have been unable to help so far. :(

--- EDIT 2 ---

After poking around some more, I'm guessing that the last device my packets see before they're lost forever (vzw-gw.customer.alter.net (157.130.202.46)) is probably a Cisco switch:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap>nmap.exe -A -T4 -P0 -p0- 157.130.202.46
[...]
Device type: broadband router|router|switch|WAP
Running: Cisco embedded, Cisco IOS 12.X|15.X
OS CPE: cpe:/o:cisco:ios:12.2 cpe:/h:cisco:870_router cpe:/o:cisco:ios:12 cpe:/h:cisco:2960_switch cpe:/h:cisco:aironet_ap1250 cpe:/o:cisco:ios:12.4 cpe:/h:cisco:catalyst_7200 cpe:/o:cisco:ios:15
OS details: Cisco 827H ADSL router (IOS 12.2), Cisco 870 router or 2960 switch (IOS 12.2 - 12.4), Cisco Aironet 1250 WAP (IOS 12.4), Cisco C7200 router (IOS 15)
Network Distance: 10 hops
[...]
```

It also seems to act inconsistently, dropping MOST pings, but replying to others:

```
$ ping verizonwireless.com
PING verizonwireless.com (162.115.16.90) 56(84) bytes of data.
From vzw-gw.customer.alter.net (157.130.202.46) icmp_seq=54 Packet filtered
From vzw-gw.customer.alter.net (157.130.202.46) icmp_seq=233 Packet filtered
From vzw-gw.customer.alter.net (157.130.202.46) icmp_seq=234 Packet filtered
From vzw-gw.customer.alter.net (157.130.202.46) icmp_seq=336 Packet filtered
From vzw-gw.customer.alter.net (157.130.202.46) icmp_seq=409 Packet filtered
From vzw-gw.customer.alter.net (157.130.202.46) icmp_seq=410 Packet filtered
From vzw-gw.customer.alter.net (157.130.202.46) icmp_seq=520 Packet filtered
From vzw-gw.customer.alter.net (157.130.202.46) icmp_seq=593 Packet filtered
```

--- EDIT 3 ---

[Looks like I'm not the only one...](http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/377420-can-not-access-website)

Unfortunately, that thread was back from 2013 doesn't look like it was ever resolved.

Comment: Can you change your WAN IP easily? Have you tried this?

Comment: @Linef4ult Not really. See edits. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that your IP address could have been hijacked at one time and is now on what they call a blacklist. If that's the case then your being permanently blocked from connecting to verizonwireless.com probably to prevent Denial of Service Attacks.

Their are actually three types of lists on the network for access control or blockage.  Blacklists, Whitelists and Greylists.

You can do a search on google or bing to find out the exact definitions of each type.

Should you be on such a list you can also do a search to find out.  It is possible to become removed from a list should you have become blacklisted but the network administrator from the site your being denied access will probably want proof that you have cleaned your system of the offending hijack tool that is causing your ip address or domain to necessitate being put on a blacklist.

As a sidebar you might also want to search for the description of a botnet as most likely your ip address or domain was hijacked and became part of this world wide web internet bot network which is why you became blacklisted.

It's also possible that on some network routers you could have accidentally gotten your ip / domain address somehow placed into your routers domain list dictionary causing you to be blocked.

In some executive suites where many individual sub routers could be connected into a master router, its possible that the master router could have a domain block feature for certain addresses.  So while you many have access to your individual routers list, you may not have access to clear the main routers list table.

Comment: Isn't this a terrible, horrible idea? Would this not cause endless headaches for users? Especially since this is just a residential DHCP lease, if this address is blacklisted, won't that just cause breakage all over the Internet, as IP addresses float from customer to customer?

Comment: TBH its a poor answer. IPs are *rarely* generally blacklisted, they just blacklisted for SMTP(a single port) as a necessary function of the internet. Yours is part of the dynamic pool so SMTP *IS* blocked, but that has nothing to do with browsing.

Comment: Unfortunately for me, this looks to have likely been the issue. See my comment above in reply to Line for details. Thanks, Cole.

Comment: In the original question, the user was not browsing but trying to reach a specific IP address, mainly VerizonWireless.com

Comment: I do a lot of public remote support and I receive calls for this at least twice a week.  Granted it happens more specifically with email accounts, but regardless the blacklisting occurs.  About 90 percent of the time it can be remedied by running Malwarebytes or a similar Malware, Anti-Virus, Rootkit, etc., detection and cleaning utility. Also  check and make sure your IE 9,10,11 Internet Options / Connections/ LAN Settings / Proxy has not been redirected.   Homepage settings are located on the Internet Options / General Tab. Finaly check the Security Tab for Restricted sites.

Comment: If your being blocked only on a single user workstation, it's possible that your HOSTS file could have been modified.  I once had a customer account where one of the other employees modified another users HOSTS file as a practical joke.  Then to cover up their antics they modified their own and several other users HOSTS file.  This backfired on them in the end and their employment contract actually had a clause regarding such conduct, making them also financially responsible for the

Comment: **LIne4ult,**  I liked your suggestion of turning off the router for 24 hours or even trying a different router thusly supplying a different connection address.That may work most of the time unless they are also tracking individual MAC addresses from the requesting workstation.  However that does not change the ISP modem and mac connection info.  MAC addresses are unique to a particular  router, workstation and or lan adapter hardware connection. I am finding more of the latest routers and ISP are using this capability to specifically pinpoint a connection and problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
 10   358 ms   133 ms   175 ms  xe-3-3-3.gw10.ewr6.alter.net [157.130.91.85]
 11     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 12     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 13     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 14  vzw-gw.customer.alter.net [157.130.0.110]  reports: Destination net unreachable.
```

The site *IS* up for me but ICMP is reporting unreachable. So lets try another connection(Different ISP, Different country):

```
 18     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 19     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 20     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 21     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 22     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

Site is still up for 80/443. So ICMP to that server doent work. Ignore it. You've tried multiple machines(browser,firewall,plugins ruled out) and other connections. The only common thing is the block you're coming from. So unless you've been marked a DOS-er(unlikely) it points to a bad config on Verizons side.

Leaving your modem off for 24hrs may cause your lease to expire on the CMTS and you'll get a new IP. Might help but as it'll probably be from the same block I'm sceptical. Other option is to ask Verizon to look into it but good luck with that.

Comment: I left my router off overnight and connected a spare one in the morning. I received a new IP address from a different /16 and am now able to access verizonwireless.com. So looks like that IP address and/or block probably did get blacklisted. As further support, I Google'd my previous /16 and found that according to [cleantalk](https://cleantalk.org/) that /16 saw a rise in spam origination starting sometime in July - August, which is well within the time frame since I last checked VZW. Thanks for your help!